# Using old web reference class with new web service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, asmx

I have web service used by about a dozen C# projects and sites. The return type for one of my web methods (a class type) has changed to add a new property. The one (of the dozen) projects I'm working has the updated reference class to reflect the new property change on the client side and works fine.

My question is, for the other 11 projects that also reference this service, will NOT updating the local proxy class to reflect this change cause them to break? Basically, when the request to this web method (with the updated return type) is made, and that new field is present in the response, but not able to be bound to a local class property, will it break?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't change the inputs of the webservice I don't think it would break.  We do that all the time, add new functions, properties etc into a service and update just the site that will be using the new stuff.  The problem comes in when your changing the inputs and what the service expects.  Or you change the type of the value(s) of what's being returned and the receiving program expects one thing but now it's receiving a different type / value potentially.

I think you would be ok but I would HIGHLY recommend testing it with a site that is still using the old references to validate your ok.

Comment: The original questions states clearly: "The return type for one of my web methods (a class type) has changed to add a new property". So that's it a breaking change.

Comment: right but just adding a new property may not break it if the requesting service isn't looking for a specific order.  Chances are good it will break but not necessarily.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If you're using WCF to expose your web service, you can use versioning:

[Service versioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731060.aspx)

See "Data Contract Versioning" for your case.

If you're using .asmx services it will fail.

Comment: Even if I told you it will fail, give it a try. Depending on the Framework version, adding a new property sometimes is tolerated. It depends on the client side.

Comment: I tried adding a property to the service's return type class, didn't update my local (didn't refresh the web reference), and it seemed to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I determined that it does not break it. Thanks for the replies.